# Spring Data JPA query 4 time faster with java.sql.Date than java.util.Date

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I created a regular entity with the usage of `java.sql.Date` for the first time. After that, I changed the import to `java.util.Date` and I experienced that the query takes much more time than before.
I started to investigate the issue and I realized that if I add the `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` to `java.util.Date`, it becomes fast again. 
This behavior is weird because in both of the cases 0 value was fetched from the database so we cannot say that it happened because of the entity's Date conversion.
We are using Oracle database and the corresponding date column has `DATE` data type.

- `java.util.Date`: 30-35 secs
- `java.sql.Date`: 7-8 secs

Do you have any idea what can cause this slowness in case of `java.util.Date`?

Comment: I strongly believe that is because `java.util.Date` has a time component to itself while `java.sql.Date` does not

Comment: I have the same feeling but if zero rows got fetched why it is important?

Comment: Since you are not saying what the initial time of the query was/to what it increased, its impossible to tell if its justified. If the query is stiell below 1 second I wouldn't put mich thought into it. It can have many many reasons. And without digging into type handling on hibernate or oracle side its probably impossible to pin it down

Answer (score 0):

To Summarize,

The `java.sql` package contains `JDBC` types that are aligned with the types defined by the `SQL` standard.

The type `java.util.Date` contains both date and time information, up to millisecond precision. But it doesn't directly relate to any `SQL` type.

So, I wouldn't rather much worry about performance unless its absolutely necessary.

Comment: In our case the performance is critical, so that's why I am focusing on that. Both cases the application worked fine, just with the util version it is much slower even though there is not retrieved data from the database. 
I have that strong feeling that when the Spring Data JPA repository builds the query it relies on the different entity property types and the performance overhead is added during the query creation.